# Same background image gets displayed multiple times on the webpage

Tags: web, responsive-images, website-deployment

I've build a simple web page which includes a **background image** in the **body tag** and the **background-size** is set to **cover** in css file.When i resize my chrome window the original image gets displayed adjacent to same image and so on just like a collage.How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add following CSS code to your stylesheet

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the lightning fast reply.It worked fine for me.

Comment: Well i think it has to be "background-repeat: no-repeat", but anyways it wasn't that hard to figure.

Comment: I just changed if someone else will come here.